# How to display Ajax error message in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

**script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.v_name').each(function() {
    $(this).on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      var dat, id ;
      id = $(this).attr('id');
     dat = JSON.parse(data);
      $('#' + id).html(dat.name.toUpperCase());
    });

  });
</script>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= best_in_place vehicle,:name, class: "v_name", id: vehicle.id%></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'.html_safe, vehicle, method: :delete,  remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure to delete <b>\"#{vehicle.name}\"?</b>", commit: "OK" }, title: "Delete Vehicle", class: "btn btn-danger delete_vehicle" %>

    </td>
</tr>       
<%end%>
```

**vehicles_controller.rb**

```
    class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_vehicle, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource

   # skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # GET /vehicles
  # GET /vehicles.json
  def index
    @q = Vehicle.search(params[:q])
    @vehicles = @q.result(:distinct => true).order_by([:updated_at, :desc]).page(params[:page]).per(5)
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new
  end

  # GET /vehicles/1
  # GET /vehicles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /vehicles/new
  def new

  end

  # GET /vehicles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /vehicles
  # POST /vehicles.json
  def create
    params[:vehicle][:name] = params[:vehicle][:name].upcase if !params[:vehicle][:name].nil?
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new(vehicle_params)
    @vehicles = Vehicle.all.order_by([:updated_at, :desc]).page(params[:page]).per(5)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @vehicle.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Vehicle was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @vehicle }
        format.js
      else
        format.js
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @vehicle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /vehicles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /vehicles/1.json
  def update
        params[:vehicle][:name] = params[:vehicle][:name].upcase if !params[:vehicle][:name].nil?

    respond_to do |format|

      if @vehicle.update(vehicle_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @vehicle, notice: 'Vehicle was successfully updated.' }
        format.json {render json: @vehicle, status: :ok}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @vehicle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /vehicles/1
  # DELETE /vehicles/1.json
  def destroy
    @vehicle.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to vehicles_url, notice: "#{@vehicle.name} deleted successfully" }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js { render :layout => false}
    end
  end

  def vehicle_search

    @q = Vehicle.search(params[:q])
    @vehicles = @q.result(:distinct  => true).order_by([:updated_at, :desc]).page(params[:page]).per(5)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_vehicle
      @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def vehicle_params
      params.require(:vehicle).permit(:name, :created_at, :updated_at)
    end
end
```

**vehicle.rb**

```
 class Vehicle
  include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, :format => {:with => /[1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]{3,}/}
  has_many :pre_processings
  has_many :batch_counts


end
```

How to display Ajax error message in rails?

Here I am update name to uppercase using above script. If there is duplicate names it's show error message through Ajax how's it possible.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

**Ajax**

Most people think the `error` hook of the JQuery Ajax function provides the ability to engage with exceptions delivered through it, but in fact that is designed to show *ajax* errors; IE if you receive a response from the server, it will be classed as a "success", unless you explicitly set an error response in the headers.

This is my own experience, it could be wrong, but I found the best way is to distinguish the returned message in your `success` function, unless of course you're able to render an error within your Rails response.

[This tutorial](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/ajax-and-json-error-handling-on-rails/) explains what I mean:

--

His example of handling errors without setting the error header:

```
if @order.save
   #...
else
   format.json { render :json => { :error => @order.errors } }
end


$(document).on "ajax:success", "form", (xhr, data, response) ->
   if data.error
      for message of data
         $('#errors ul').append '<li>' + data.error[message] + '</li>'
```

This is if you don't send a bad request header, which is what you're doing.

If you *do* send a bad request header (IE ajax picks it up as being erroneous), you can use the following:

```
if @order.save
   #...
else
   format.json { render :json => { :error => @order.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422 }
end


$(document).on "ajax:error", "form", (evt, xhr, status, error) ->
   errors = xhr.responseJSON.error
   for message of errors
      $('#errors ul').append '<li>' + errors[message] + '</li>'
```

As mentioned in another comment, this allows you to use the `ajax:error` callback for [Rails' ajax functionality](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2008/7/23/using-http-status-codes-for-rails-ajax-error-handling):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
$("document).on('ajax:error', '.v_name', function(evt, xhr, status, error) {
      // process errors here
});
```

---

As an aside, you need to fix some parts of your code:

1. **Script**

Never put your script "in-line" in your view, as you are doing now. Rails uses [unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), meaning that all your JS logic should be kept in your `/assets/javascripts` files, as below:

```
 #app/assets/javascripts/application.js
 $(".v_name").on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      var dat, id ;
      id = $(this).attr('id');
      dat = JSON.parse(data);
      $('#' + id).html(dat.name.toUpperCase());
 });
```

You also don't need to use the `.each` function - Javascript binds to specific elements. If you bind it to a *type* of element, it will be invoked for each instance of it.

2. **ERB**

In your *view*, you're using the following code:

```
<% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= best_in_place vehicle,:name, class: "v_name", id: vehicle.id%></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'.html_safe, vehicle, method: :delete,  remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure to delete <b>\"#{vehicle.name}\"?</b>", commit: "OK" }, title: "Delete Vehicle", class: "btn btn-danger delete_vehicle" %>

    </td>
</tr>       
<%end%>
```

This is very haphazard (you can do it cleaner):

```
<% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
   <%= content_tag :tr do %>
      <%= content_tag :td, best_in_place(vehicle, :name, class: "v_name", id: vehicle.id) %>
      <%= content_tag :td, link_to('<i class="fa fa-trash-o">&nbsp;</i>', vehicle, method: :delete,  remote: true, data: { confirm: "Are you sure to delete <b>\"#{vehicle.name}\"?</b>", commit: "OK" }, title: "Delete Vehicle", class: "btn btn-danger delete_vehicle") %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You should also note you should keep your ERB and HTML code as separate as possible. For example, in your `link_to`, you have the following:

```
link_to('<i class="fa fa-trash-o">&nbsp;</i>'
```

This is very bad practice. I've left it "as is" for now because it seems you're using some web font icons which require that structure. However, in future, you need refrain from putting pure HTML into ERB. Rails has as many [`helpers`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/) as you need to keep it clean.

3. **DRY**

Although your controller *seems* to be okay, you really need to make it as DRY as possible. [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) means putting as many thins into their own methods as possible, not being specific for the sake of it, and generally keeping your [controller as thin](http://www.slideshare.net/damiansromek/thin-controllers-fat-models-proper-code-structure-for-mvc) as you can.

For example...

```
#app/controllers/vehicles_controller.rb
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_vehicle_search, only: [:index, :vehicle_search]
    private

    def vehicle_search
       @q = Vehicle.search(params[:q])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just add below script error function in ajax. It works form me.

```
   $('.v_name').each(function() {
   $(this).on('ajax:error', function(event, xhr, data, status) {
        alert("Please find out error duplicate values!");

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a file at `views/vehicles/create.js.erb` and write javascript code to update view when success or show error messages